# Unexpected directive 'LoginPage' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am developing an application using ionic 2. The main features of the application is login screen and then appear a dash board with side menu. Side menu will not be in login screen. I did it. but do not know the following error is coming out again and again.

The error is

> Unexpected directive 'LoginPage' imported by the module 'AppModule'.
>   Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Here I'm giving my code..

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';    
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';    
import { MyApp } from './app.component';    
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';    
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';    
import { LoginPage } from "./login/login";    
import { MenuComponent } from "./menu.component";    
@NgModule({    
  declarations: [  
    MyApp,    
    HomePage,   
    ListPage,    
    MenuComponent    
  ],

  imports: [    
    BrowserModule,    
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),   
    LoginPage   
  ],

  bootstrap: [IonicApp],

  entryComponents: [ 
    MyApp,    
    HomePage,   
    ListPage,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})

export class AppModule {}


App.component.ts

import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';  
import { LoginService } from "./login/login.service";
import { LoginPage } from "./login/login"; 
import { MenuComponent } from "./menu.component";

@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #baseNav></ion-nav>',
})
export class MyApp {

  @ViewChild('baseNav') nav: Nav;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen, private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.initializeApp();
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    const componentStack: Array<{page: Component}> = [{
      page: MenuComponent
    }];
    if (!this.loginService.isLoggedIn) {

      componentStack.push({ page: LoginPage });
    }

    this.nav.insertPages(0, componentStack, { animate: false });
  }


  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

How may I resolve this issue...? I'm using Angular 4.

Comment: Is it really that hard to format your code correctly? Anyway, you can only import modules, not "pages". You probably want to put `LoginPage` into `declarations`.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-should-i-import

Comment: imports are for modules. you need to add pages to declarations

Answer (score 19):

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    MyApp,    
    HomePage,    
    ListPage,    
    MenuComponent,
    LoginPage      // loginPgae will be here not in imports  
  ],    
  imports: [   
    BrowserModule,    
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)        
  ],    
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],    
  entryComponents: [    
    MyApp,    
    HomePage,    
    ListPage,    
    MenuComponent    
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]    
})
```

Answer (score 13):

In your code, You have written "LoginPage" in Imports in @ngModule.
Instead, write it in the declaration and in EntryComponents.

```js
@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    MenuComponent,
    LoginPage       //add LoginPage here
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],

  bootstrap: [IonicApp],

  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    MenuComponent,
    LoginPage        //add LoginPage here
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler }]
})
```

You have to Declare your components in Declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The way you import components into a module is you add them to the declarations. This is true for in general for all component imports.

declarations: [
          Component1,
          Component2,
          ...
        ],